# Getting variables out of a function in R

Tags: r, function, global-variables

So here is some backghround info:
I have created a question and answer function in R. After the user calls  the function they are prompted a succession of questions that will eventually be used to populate a report using R markdown. The function is divided into sections that follow the intended report and each section ends with a data.frame that has the question category, the answer and the name of the variable. In total there are 17 sections which means that there are 17 data.frames that get strung together using rbind function before the function writes the final data.frame to a .csv, saves it to a directory and exits. This function works well and I have no problems with it at all.

My problem lies in the fact that once the function ends I am not able to call the variables back to the console. this is a problem because if I would like to populate a report with the questions in R markdown I cannot because they only exist in the realm of the function.

What I have tried already:

1. I have already tried creating a list (using c()) containing the variables from each section and had the function return the list. however this did not work since it not only returns a small portion of the list and it only populates the readlines I passed to the variables. I need the be able to call the variable and receive what was answered.
2. I have called back the the .csv that was saved by the function and attempted to use the assign function to assign the variable name to the variable answer. This worked only when I entered one line at a time and fails when I attempt to assign column 1 to column 2. Considering there are 163 questions assigning them one at a time is a waste of time. I have even tried using the lapply and sapply functions to do this but there always a failure with the assign function

I need to be able to bring out the 163 variables that were created during the execution of the function. Here is a sample of the function for whom ever is interested to play around with.

```
    sv<-function(){
    Name<-readline("What is your Name?")
   Date<-readline("What date is the site audit set for?(mm/dd/yyyy)")
   Number<-readline("What is the project number")
   Bname<-readline("What is the buildings name?")
   ADD<-readline("What is the buildings address?(123 Fake Street)")
   City<-readline("What city is the bulding located in?")
   Pcode<-readline("What is the buildings postal code?")
   HOO<-readline("What are the building's hours of operation?")
   PHONE<-readline("What is the building's telephone number? (555-555-5555)")
   FAX<-readline("What is the Fire Department's fax number? (555-555-5555)")
   CONTACT<-readline("Who is the contact person for the Building? (First name,     Last name)")
}
```

I thank you in advance for you help. Also please note I have searched through the site and saw similar questions but was not able to make the suggestions work so I apologize if this is redundant. Rember I need to be able to call Name and receive the name I entered once the function has done its thing.

Comment: It is possible to pull the variables out of the function environment if you create the function with `local`. However, this would seem like a hack. Why can't the function return the values you want, or save them to a file or database?

Comment: Return a named list? For example `res$Name <- Name<-readline("What is your Name?")`, return `res` and then you can get the result by `res$Name`?

Comment: Thanks all for answering. I have tried those suggestions and it is still not what I need. I'll keep plugging away at this thank you all for your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the global assignment operator:

```
> sv <- function(){
+   Name <<- readline("What is your Name?")
+ }
> sv()
What is your Name?mkemp6
> print(Name)
[1] "mkemp6"
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked with your example. i'll try it for the whole function. Its weird though I have tried that one before and it nothing happened not sure why but at least now I can get it to work on a small scale.